# OriendDB apply edge multiple times in a match-query

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

guys. The question is how to apply a relationship (edge) multiple times between two vertices. Remark: The path, of course, can go through other cities.
In Cypher I can use asteriks * to do this and the query would look like this one:

```
MATCH path=(start:City{name:'London'})-[has_train|travelling_to*1..4]->(end:City{name:'Berlin'})
RETURN path
```

So what about OrientDb? Should I use traverse() in this case? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi, I use 3.0.10 version